# Converting 2D Numpy array of grayscale values to a PIL image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Say I have a 2D Numpy array of values on the range 0 to 1, which represents a grayscale image.  How do I then convert this into a PIL Image object?  All attempts so far have yielded extremely strange scattered pixels or black images.

```
for x in range(image.shape[0]):
    for y in range(image.shape[1]):
        image[y][x] = numpy.uint8(255 * (image[x][y] - min) / (max - min))

#Create a PIL image.
img = Image.fromarray(image, 'L')
```

In the code above, the numpy array image is normalized by (image[x][y] - min) / (max - min) so every value is on the range 0 to 1.  Then it is multiplied by 255 and cast to an 8 bit integer.  This should, in theory, process through Image.fromarray with mode L into a grayscale image - but the result is a set of scattered white pixels.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), a maintained fork of PIL, or are you using the original PIL?

Comment: +MattDMo I'm using the most recent version of Pillow, and I'm using in particular Python 3.4

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: +MattDMo I edited, but there's not very much information I can add.  This is less of a specific issue and more of a general problem.

Answer (score 45):

I think the answer is wrong. The Image.fromarray( ____ , 'L') function seems to only work properly with an array of integers between 0 and 255. I use the np.uint8 function for this.

You can see this demonstrated if you try to make a gradient.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# gradient between 0 and 1 for 256*256
array = np.linspace(0,1,256*256)

# reshape to 2d
mat = np.reshape(array,(256,256))

# Creates PIL image
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat * 255) , 'L')
img.show()
```

Makes a clean gradient

vs

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# gradient between 0 and 1 for 256*256
array = np.linspace(0,1,256*256)

# reshape to 2d
mat = np.reshape(array,(256,256))

# Creates PIL image
img = Image.fromarray( mat , 'L')
img.show()
```

Has the same kind of artifacting.

Comment: np.uint8 is important. I used .astype(int) before, also scaling 0...1 values by multiplying by 255, but got completely black images only. uint8 was the fix.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you question, you want to get a grayscale image using PIL.

If this is the case, you do not need to multiply each pixels by 255.

The following worked for me

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Creates a random image 100*100 pixels
mat = np.random.random((100,100))

# Creates PIL image
img = Image.fromarray(mat, 'L')
img.show()
```

Comment: I tried this and got very obvious image artifacting - There were visible vertical bars every 7 or so pixels.  Is it possible the latest version of Pillow is just straight up broken?

Comment: I also got artifacts. If I use img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat), 'L'), then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat), 'L')`

or

`im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat))`

Apparently it accepts type np.uint8(insert array here), also may be able to remove 'L' for conciseness.