# how to create an gray-scale image from existing 2D array data in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a problem creating a grey-scale image from existing 2D array in python.

Supposing I have a 2D array, X at dimension 504x896 data type is unit8. How could I create a gray-scale image from this 2D array? Will OpenCV provide an function for it or do I have to include other image processing library?

---

I have tried this but it did not work for some reason. Given a 2D array z

```
dim = z.shape
h =  dim[0]
w = dim[1]

copy_image = np.zeros((h,w,1), np.uint8)
copy_image = z.copy();
cv2.imwrite("cpImage.bmp",copy_image)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558523/converting-2d-numpy-array-of-grayscale-values-to-a-pil-image/37559440#37559440

Comment: It needs to be a 2D array.

Answer (score -1):

This should work as expected. I have used Float32 as both arguments cv.CvtColor must have the same depth.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
nArray = np.zeros((504, 896), np.float32) #Create the arbitrary input img
h,w = nArray.shape
cArray1 = cv2.CreateMat(h, w, cv2.CV_32FC3)
cArray2 = cv2.fromarray(nArray)
cv2.CvtColor(cArray2, cArray1, cv2.CV_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("cpImage.bmp", cArray1)
```

Comment: This does not work on recent versions of python.