# TypeError: Cannot handle this data type - Wrong mode for `PIL.Image.fromarray`?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use [`PIL.Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]])
im = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")
im.save("test.png")
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

I expected to see 3 pixels red, green and blue.

However, if I omit `mode` keyword parameter as shown in the docs example, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

And if I set `mode="RGB"`, the saved image file `test.png` and the `matplotlib` window both look like this:

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack your three arrays and convert them to `uint8` type based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10463090/4932316) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47598847/4932316) answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

a = (np.dstack(([255, 0, 0],[0, 255, 0],[0, 0, 255]))).astype(np.uint8) 

im = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")
im.save("test.png")
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

**Alternate option is** to add extra dimension to your input array making it of shape `(1, 3, 3)`

```
a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]], dtype=np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes mode `RGB` should be 3x8-bit pixels. However, `numpy.ndarray` has type `int64` by default:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

That's where

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

came from. If I set the correct 8-bit `dtype` keyword for the array, everything works fine, even without specifying the `mode` keyword:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]])
im = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")
im.save("test.png")
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]