# How to save 2D float numpy arrays losslessly into a grayscale image while preserving resolution?

Tags: python, image

I have some Temperature field values which I want to convert to grayscale Image while **preserving the resolution**. (For example, if it's a (100x100) size float array, then the conversion should be a grayscale (100x100) image).Then I will process the image and convert it back to Temperature numpy array. The image processing part can be considered as a black-box process.

It's important that the conversion is **lossless**.

Also, the code for the image processing will recognise .png & .jpg. ( I am not sure about recognition of other file formats including tiff. Also, even jpg formats are not preferred since they will result in lossy conversion).

My attempts so far:

- Matplotlib's `imsave()` is resolution preserving and is lossless. But it converts the image into RGB instead of grayscale. This approach is also fine with me, but I am unable to accurately convert the 3 channel RGB image back to float numpy array. For example, I took a 10x10 numpy float array `temperature`, used `plt.imsave('Temperature_profile.png',temperature)`. Then, I reopened the same image but am unable to find out an accurate way to transform it back to (10x10) float array. So, the problem is solved if there is a way to convert back 3 channel image to 2D matrix losslessly.
- PIL's `Image.fromarray()` preserves resolution and can save image as a grayscale image. But I unable to save the matrix losslessly and retrieve it back losslessly. Hence I will get wrong results. ([Converting 2D Numpy array of grayscale values to a PIL image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558523/converting-2d-numpy-array-of-grayscale-values-to-a-pil-image/47598847#47598847))
- `scipy.misc.imsave()` has deprecated.
- `imageio.imwrite()` gives a warning about lossy conversion. ("Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8").
- `opencv` and `cv2` for some reason is not getting recognised by my spyder environment (python 3.7,Anaconda 4.7.12).

Comment: Hi, sorry I was occupied by some other work. Yes, your answers were helpful for what I had wanted. But again, when I fed the TIFF images into my image processing code, the resulting output image it gave was in uint8 format. But the values were off only by a small margin. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a lossless image format that can save floats:

- PNG can only save up to 16-bit integer,
- JPEG is not lossless and only 8-bit integer,
- GIF is integer and 8-bit,
- NetPBM is up to 16-bit integer only.

so use TIFF with lossless compression, or no compression. Alternatively you could use [PFM](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/) - Portable Float Map.

---

Here is a demonstration:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate a small float image in Numpy array
grey32 = np.random.randn(2,3).astype(np.float32)                                           

# Convert to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(grey32).save('test.tif')                                                   

# Read back from disk and convert to Numpy array
reloaded = np.array(Image.open('test.tif'))                                                

# Inspect
print(grey32)

array([[-0.28032717, -1.7696048 , -0.9811929 ],
       [-0.7785768 , -1.2427857 , -0.33241433]], dtype=float32)

print(reloaded)                                                                           

array([[-0.28032717, -1.7696048 , -0.9811929 ],
       [-0.7785768 , -1.2427857 , -0.33241433]], dtype=float32)
```

---

If your viewer is incapable of showing TIFF files containing floats, you can always convert them to something viewable with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick float.tif -auto-level viewable.png
```

I know that [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/://) and [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) are both good Python libraries for dealing with TIFF floats.

Comment: Very good answer, easy to save image_depth in a H x W fashion with these formats.