# Creating a gray-scale image from an 2D array of pixel values

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library, libpng

I am trying to change the values from a gray scale PNG image and then create an image from those changed values.

The first step I took was using a [python implementation of libpng](https://github.com/f1nsternacht/libpng).
With that I was able to get a list of all the pixel values of the PNG. It is a gray scale image so the values where from 0 to 100. I do a quick algorithm to change the values. And then I try to create it into a new PNG file. Its all on a single line so I use regex to format it into a 2D array.

I attempted to use this that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558523/converting-2d-numpy-array-of-grayscale-values-to-a-pil-image)

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


pixels = [[100,0,0],[0,100,0],[0,0,100]]
# Convert the pixels into an array using numpy
array = np.array(pixels)

print(array)

# Use PIL to create an image from the new array of pixels
new_image = Image.fromarray(array, 'L')
new_image.save('testing.png')
```

But I guess the formatting that PIL uses is different from what the libpng is so instead of making an image that looks like 3 white pixels diagonally, I only get 1 white pixel on the top left. So either I change the values I am getting from libpng so that numpy works, or I find something in libpng that will allow me to change the values directly and create the new file.

Comment: Why are you reading the image with `libpng`  instead of just using `PIL`. In that way you use the same library both for reading and writing.

Comment: @SebastianKreft I was using it mostly for the convenience since I was playing with some filter algorithms. Unless PIL can also do that, I might just start using PIL for everything.

Comment: Depends on what kind of filtering you need. PIL is a very complete library so chances are there is there. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageFilter.html

Comment: @SebastianKreft oh thank you for this. I will definitely be using this more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that you are not setting the right data type for the array. If you call `array = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')` then your code will work.

Comment: Yes this is working, but the picture is darker than it should. I grabbed the original pixel data and created it but it is a lot darker. Do you happen to know what range the pixel values are? 0 being darkest, but what is the lightest?

Comment: The maximum value is 255 (the maximum value of a `uint8`). That's why I suggest to use PIL for reading as well, as then you only need to think in one domain.