# Viewing 3D array

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have 3D array normalized (between 0 and 1) data, I would like view it 3D format in python [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWygs.png), with the colors matching the values in the array.

Comment: use PIL/pillow - you can set each pixel's value one-by-one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558523/converting-2d-numpy-array-of-grayscale-values-to-a-pil-image

Comment: You can either take each layer of a numpy array and turn it into an image, or if it's only "viewing" (debugging, etc.) you could use the PyCharm IDE in debug mode.

Comment: @mozway That wasn't my edit

Comment: @Yoosuf can you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 3D array

You could use [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) with a 3D projection:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.random(size=(20, 10, 5))

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')

grid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(a.shape[2]),
                   np.arange(a.shape[1]),
                   np.arange(a.shape[0]))

x = ax.scatter(*grid, c=a)
plt.colorbar(x)
```

[image: 3D scatter]

##### 2D array

You could use [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.random(size=(50,100))

plt.imshow(a, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
```

output:

[image: matplotlib imshow]