# Is there a way in python to stack arrays of pixels of same size (such as a z-stack)?

Tags: arrays, numpy, 3d, imaging

I just want to sort of clarify for example could I somehow stack a few 2D arrays into an image?

```
array1=[[0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,7.6,7,7.2,0]
        [0,7.6,7,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0]]

array2=[[0,0,0,0,0]
        [0,7.6,7,7.2,0]
        [0,7.6,7,0,0]
        [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

And then see them in 3D space such as the cube example at [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/displaying-3d-images-in-python/)

I haven't really tried much other than trying to make other things using the geeks for geeks code. So any direction at all would be appreciated.

Comment: The visualization you expect is unclear. In your link this is 3D scatter, in you case you have a defined grid. Can you provide a schematic of what you expect?

Comment: yes @mozway If you look further down the link at the cube example like I mentioned, its one under the scatter example. I would like to layer it how they do to make the cube. In my case it would be a z-stack received from a microscope of a cell. But I Was just trying to make it as easy as an example as possible. In this example they use an Array of ones basically to make this cube. I am wondering if I can use an array of pixel values to make an image in 3D as well. Does this make sense?

Comment: If this is microscopy pictures, why don't you use a dedicated tool like ImageJ? The issue with the cube visualization is that you will only see the external elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming numpy arrays as input (not python lists), you can use [`numpy.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.13/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
out = np.dstack((array1, array2))
```

output:

```
array([[[0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0. ],
        [7.6, 7.6],
        [7. , 7. ],
        [7.2, 7.2],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0. ],
        [7.6, 7.6],
        [7. , 7. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ]]])
```

Although, if you want to plot, it might be easier to have a list of the arrays and loop.

Comment: I have seen the np.stack, however I guess I did not word my question well enough. Is there a way to then see an image of this array in three dimensional space, such as the cube example in my link?

Comment: What would the color be?

Comment: The color in particular does not matter right now. But if I could do it even in greyscale that would be a great step in the right direction. @mozway

Comment: I won't be able to have a look now, but there are ways using a meshgrid

Comment: Ok, I can look into meshgrid

Comment: @Sam check this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487097/16343464) of mine, but this is probably only practical with small 3D arrays if you want to be able to see something

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for something like this. I am representing the depth dimension with different colors and an added depth of +z

```
A = np.array([ [*array1],[*array2] ])
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
z_c = ['k','blue']
[ax.scatter(z+A[z,y,x], y, x, c=z_c[z]) for z in range(A.shape[0]) \
 for y in range(A.shape[1]) for x in range(A.shape[2])]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I have been able to do this far, I actually was wondering if there’s any chance you could create a representation sort of like pymol potentially? Where there is just a dot in dark space corresponding to one array element

Comment: Yes you can Sam.

Comment: Do you potentially have any example of that? Or what API potentially that is used, etc. This would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14460178/andrew-r-garcia

Comment: Not sure how you tag but do you have any examples? @Andrew-r-garcia

Comment: Mozway’s example above is quite helpful. Keep in mind what you are trying to plot is not 3D but rather 4D